# Save output of the_content_rss into variable

Tags: functions

How can I save the output of the function `the_content_rss` into a string variable?

Answer (score 1):

[`the_content_rss()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content_rss) is deprecated. You should be using [`the_content_feed()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content_feed), but that is a secondary problem. Both functions `echo` content. What you want is the `get_*` variant-- [`get_the_content_feed()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content_feed).

That is a general rule, by the way, but not a 100% consistent one. Many functions starting with `the_` will output content immediately and there tends to be a `get_` variant that will return a string (or other) for you to use.